# How to allow user to input a color (non hex or rbga) for list customization but make sure it's valid

Tags: javascript

Just wondering if anyone knows the best way to implement this into code. Is there a method for checking if a string is a valid color?

I want to allow the user to click a button to change color and then enter a color name, changing the background color of their list.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp

Comment: Are you trying to check if a word is a valid color name?

Comment: Correct! I want the user to be able to enter the color they wish, but make sure it's not just some random word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the valid color names from the specification [CSS Color Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/), set `pattern` attribute to `RegExp` as string from array delimited by `|` for `OR`; set `required` attribute at `input type="text"` element, provide notification to user at adjacent `<label>` element whether or not color name is valid.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const cssColor = "https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/";
  const input = document.querySelector("form input[type=text]");
  const button = document.querySelector("form input[type=button]");
  const img = document.querySelector("form img");
  const span = document.querySelector("span");

  fetch(cssColor)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(html => {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
      const colorNames = Array.from(
        doc.querySelectorAll(".named-color-table dfn")
        , ({textContent}) => textContent
      );
      console.log(colorNames);
      input.pattern = colorNames
        .concat(colorNames.map(color => color.toUpperCase())).join("|");
      button.addEventListener("click", e => {
        if (input.checkValidity())
          img.style.backgroundColor = input.value;
      });
      input.removeAttribute("disabled");
      button.removeAttribute("disabled");
      span.style.display = "none";
    })
}
```

```css
form * {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#colorName:invalid+[for=colorName]:after {
  content: "Invalid color";
  color: red;
}

#colorName:valid+[for=colorName]:after {
  content: "Valid color";
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<span>loading valid color names..</span>
<form>
  <input id="colorName" type="text" required pattern="" disabled/><label for="colorName"></label><br>
  <input type="button" value="click" disabled><br>
  <img alt="color" width="100px" height="100px">
</form>
```

Comment: @JaromandaX At firefox click `Raw headers` at `Network` tab after clicking `Inspect Element (Q)`. Not sure why firebug does not display all of the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by assigning the color to a style attribute, and checking that the attribute has a length > 0 will do the job

e.g. you could do it like this

```
function testColor(color) {
    var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.style.backgroundColor = ''; // clear it first - which makes it valid
    head.style.backgroundColor = color;
    return head.style.backgroundColor.length > 0;
}
```

Tested in firefox, chrome, IE and Edge