# XML request and response with fetch?

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, fetch

The Postal Service has an API that allows you to send an xml request with package weight, travel info, etc. It will return back an xml response.

How do I handle the xml response? I either need to parse the xml on the client-side, or more preferably, put the xml in a variable that I can send to my laravel backend for parsing.

Btw, I'm using react and laravel.

```
getPostagePrice = () => {
  fetch('http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingApi.dll?API=RateV4&XML=<RateV4Request USERID="XXXXXXXXXXX"><PackageID="1ST"><Service>PRIORITY</Service><ZipOrigination>44106</ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>20770</ZipDestination><Pounds>1</Pounds><Ounces>8</Ounces><Container>NONRECTANGULAR</Container><Size>LARGE</Size><Width>15</Width><Length>30</Length><Height>15</Height><Girth>55</Girth></Package></RateV4Request>', {
       method: 'get',
   }).then((response) => {
       console.log(response.text());
   }).then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml")
   ).then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: read [fetch documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) ... usually you would `.then((response) => response.text())` and the next .then would have the text available ... i.e. replace `console.log(response.text())` with `return response.text()` so that you **return** something

Comment: @JaromandaX Note, the "something" is a `Promise`, `.text()`, `.blob()`, `.arrayBuffer()`, and if implemented at the environment, `.formData()`, of `Response` object each return a `Promise`

Comment: my point was that the first .then isn't returning anything at all, and did make the point that it should return `response.text()` - so, not sure what point you're trying to make @guest271314

Comment: @JaromandaX Not trying to make a point. Only indicating that `.text()` method of  `Response` returns a `Promise`, not "something"

Comment: yeah, my wording was sloppy at the end :p

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Response.text()` returns a `Promise`, chain `.then()` to get the `Promise` value of `.text()` call.

If you are expecting a `Promise` to be returned from `getPostagePrice` function, `return` `fetch()` call from `getPostagePrice()` call.

```
getPostagePrice = () => {
  fetch('/path/to/server')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
  .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

Comment: @JasparLamarCrab See [How to allow user to input a color (non hex or rbga) for list customization but make sure it's valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361825/how-to-allow-user-to-input-a-color-non-hex-or-rbga-for-list-customization-but/44362289#44362289) for similar pattern

Comment: I had to remove the "window." part to get it to work for me (in TypeScript).  #ymmv

Answer (score 5):

Also with async/await you can do the same without lost your scope (remember that if you use .then, you only can work INSIDE the callback function).

```
async function display(){     
    const xmlFetch = await fetch("./yourXMLorXSL.xml")
    const xmlText = await xmlFetch.text()
    const xml = await (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlText, "text/xml")

    console.log(xml)
}
```